# Where are event listeners defined in npm packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dom-events, irc

I've been working on coding an [IRC bot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/irc) in nodejs as a learning project.  I've been frequently coming across event listeners such as the following:

```
bot.addListener("message", function(from, to, text, message) {
.
.
.
});
```

**Problem:** I've been looking everywhere for an explanation of where this `addListener` is defined/explained.  I can't find anything.  It is from the `irc` package in `npm`, and even after searching every github file in the `irc` package source, I find no instance of the string `addListener`.

What's going on here?  How do I figure out how this `addListener` is working, what the list of IRC events are (besides just "message"), and so forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_addlistener_event_listener

> **emitter.addListener(event, listener)**
>
> ## emitter.on(event, listener)
>
> Adds a listener to the end of the listeners array for the specified
>   event. No checks are made to see if the listener has already been
>   added. Multiple calls passing the same combination of event and
>   listener will result in the listener being added multiple times.

```
server.on('connection', function (stream) {   console.log('someone
connected!'); }); Returns emitter, so calls can be chained.
```

It usually added to object with http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor

> util.inherits(constructor, superConstructor)# Inherit the prototype
>   methods from one constructor into another. The prototype of
>   constructor will be set to a new object created from superConstructor.
>
> As an additional convenience, superConstructor will be accessible
>   through the constructor.super_ property.

```
var util = require("util"); var events = require("events");

function MyStream() {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this); }

util.inherits(MyStream, events.EventEmitter);

MyStream.prototype.write = function(data) {
    this.emit("data", data); }

var stream = new MyStream();

console.log(stream instanceof events.EventEmitter); // true console.log(MyStream.super_ === events.EventEmitter); // true

stream.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log('Received data: "' + data + '"'); }) stream.write("It works!"); // Received data: "It works!"
```

For your irc-bot you can find thid sting at https://github.com/martynsmith/node-irc/blob/master/lib%2Firc.js line 603

```
util.inherits(Client, process.EventEmitter);
```

and event fired with construction like

```
self.emit('connect'); // same file  L:665
```